# TypeError: Cannot set property 'search' of undefined

Tags: jasmine, angular5

I have searched and cannot find an answer to my issue. I have an Angular 5 project and I'm trying to run my unit tests and I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'search' of undefined
```

Here is my ts file:

```
import { Component, OnChanges, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CheckboxModule } from '@common-web-components';

import { ItemFilter } from '../../models/item-filter';
import { ItemBrandSearchResponse } from '../../models/item-brand-search-response';
import { ItemBrandSearchResponseService } from '../../services/item-brand-search-response.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-brand-filter',
  templateUrl: './item-brand-filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-brand-filter.component.css']
})
export class ItemBrandFilterComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input()
  filter: ItemFilter;

  availableCount: number;
  firstOpen: Boolean = true;
  searching: Boolean = true;
  itemBrands = new Array<ItemBrandSearchResponse>();

  constructor(private itemBrandSearchResponseService: ItemBrandSearchResponseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searching = true;
    this.firstOpen = false;
    this.getItemBrandForFilter();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (!this.firstOpen) {
      this.searching = true;
      this.getItemBrandForFilter();
    }
  }

  getItemBrandForFilter(): void {
    this.itemBrandSearchResponseService.get(this.filter).subscribe(
      results => {
        this.itemBrands = results.data;

        if (results.availableCount) {
          this.availableCount = results.availableCount;
        }
        this.searching = false;
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Error getting items');
      }
    );
  }

  getRouterLink(): string {
    return this.filter.search === '' ? '/items' : '/items/search/' + this.filter.search;
  }

}
```

And here is my spec file:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { CheckboxModule } from '@kehe-dev/connect-common-web-components';

import { ItemBrandFilterComponent } from './item-brand-filter.component';
import { ItemBrandSearchResponseService } from '../../services/item-brand-search-response.service';
import { ItemFilter } from '../../models/item-filter';

describe('Component: ItemBrandFilterComponent', () => {
  let component: ItemBrandFilterComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ItemBrandFilterComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ItemBrandFilterComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        CheckboxModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        ItemBrandSearchResponseService
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
   }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ItemBrandFilterComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.filter.search = 'test';
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', inject([ItemBrandSearchResponseService], (service: ItemBrandSearchResponseService) => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

I originally didn't have the line:

```
component.filter.search = 'test';
```

And I had the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of null
```

So I searched for that one and found an article that said I needed to set it. Now I get this new error and really just can't find anything that fits as a solution.

Comment: "why does unit testing take longer to do than the actual coding?" -- I have many answers to this. 1. Testing _is_ actual coding. 2. If you have good code, writing tests is fast--in fact, writing tests is usually _faster_ than not writing them, once you're practiced. 3. Almost everything humans design requires more testing than design, not just software.

Comment: The "once you're practiced" is the optimum phrase! I've been coding for 30+ years, but ultimately only really performing unit testing within code for the last 4-5 and until VERY recently never in front end code. My code that is being built for deployment works perfectly. The issue is getting used to how I need to setup my spec files so that Jasmine will run.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. Within the test environment my component.filter hadn't been initialized.

So I added:

```
component.filter = new ItemFilter();
```

And that fixed my issue. Pretty obvious now!

Comment: Where did you initialize at? Having the same issue, came to the same conclusion but still cant seem to get it to work.